# How to Sort one List by another List inside this first List?

Tags: java, arrays, list, sorting, object

Guys I need help to try to solve my problem.

Here it is: I have one List like: `List<Result> T` and inside this list I have another List. The `List<Result> T` has the constructor like: `Result (int a, int b, int c, int d, List<Sim> sim)`. `List<Sim>` has two attributes, `int and double` values. What I want to do is:
when I add one element in `T`, the `List<Result>` need to be sorted by `List<Sim>` **by it's double values**.

So List will be sorted in decreasing order of this double value which is on List. I tried so many things but until I didn't got any results. Every time I add one element on T, this element is added in the end of the List and the List itself it's not sorting.

```
public class Result 
{  
  int a, b, c, d;
  List<Sim> sim;

    public Result(int a, int b, int c, int d, List<Sim> sim) 
   {

    this.a = a;
    this.b = b;
    this.sim = sim;
   }

   public int compareTo(Result o)
   {
     int cmp = ((a.key == o.key) && (b.key == o.key)) ? 0 : (b.key < o.key) ? -1 : 1;           
    return cmp; 
   }
}

public class Sim
{
    int a;
    double value;

    public Sim (int a, double value)
    {
     this.a = a;
     this.value = value;
    }
}
```

I tried other types of comparators, like compare and implementing Comparable interface, but I had no luck. Can you guys please help me figure out how to solve this problem? Really appreciate your help.

[image: This is an example of what I need to do]

Guys I really appreciated all your help, sure indeed helped me figure out how to solve my problem. This is what I did:

```
    public static class SimComparator implements Comparator<Result>
{       
    public int compare(Result res1, Result res2)
    {
        double sim1 = res1.sim.get(0).sim; 
        double sim2 = res2.sim.get(0).sim;

        if (sim1 < sim2)   
        {
            return -1;        
        }           
        else if (sim1 > sim2)
        {
            return 1;    
        }                                   
        else 
        }   
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202232/discussion-on-question-by-guilherme-schults-how-to-sort-one-list-by-another-list).

Answer (score 0):

Since you have the same number of objects in both the `List<Result>` and the `List<Sim>` in each `Result` object, I think you have a one-to-one relationship between `Result` objects and `Sim` objects. I mean that it sounds like each `Result` object is related to exactly one `Sim` object. If this is true, then you should change your `Result` class to hold a single `Sim` rather than an entire list of `Sim`s:

```java
class Result {
    int a, b, c, d;
    Sim sim;

    public Result(int a, int b, int c, int d, Sim sim) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
        this.sim = sim;
    }

    // ...
}
```

Now you can easily compare `Result` objects using properties in the related `Sim` object:

```java
public int compareTo(Result o) {
    return Double.compare(this.sim.value, o.sim.value);
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I'm thinking, but I'm going to withhold my upvote until we hear back from the OP.